# Taking care of a Aging Parent

Tags: united-states, family-law, new-jersey

It is my understanding that just because an older person does things that are not wise, does not give the right of an adult child to impose guardianship on them or force them to see a doctor. It is my understanding that if they are a danger to themselves or others than a guardian can be imposed.

If a parent, over the age of 80, needs medical attention and has dementia it is my understanding that their adult children could ask for guardianship and then force the parent to see a appropriate  doctor. Is there an alternative way, one that is easier, to force the parent to see the appropriate doctor?

Comment: Where does the magic 80 number come from? How would they impose guardianship *before* "forcing the parent to see a doctor"?

Comment: I suppose that I should have left out the number 80. There is nothing magic about it. I put the number 80 there to indicate that the parent is old.

Comment: The process is necessarily difficult as there is a relatively high standard for a person to be stripped of their rights and subjected to someone else's guardianship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an alternative way, one that is easier, to force the parent
> to see the appropriate doctor?

No.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, try to invite, rather force.

> a guardian can be imposed.

Prior, ask yourself: what is needed to be solved? Who can enforce that? Why will he/she do it?

Questions to avoid disappointment.